# Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.IMigrator'

Tags: entity-framework-core

When I'm trying to add migrations with Add-Migration Initial, I have the following exception in console:

```
Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.IMigrator'. This is often because no database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' method or by using 'AddDbContext' on the application service provider. If 'AddDbContext' is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions<TContext> object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.
```

I have configured a class that inherits from DbContext below:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext, IApplicationDbContext
    {
        private readonly IMediator _mediator;
        private readonly AuditableEntitySaveChangesInterceptor _auditableEntitySaveChangesInterceptor;

        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options,
             IMediator mediator, AuditableEntitySaveChangesInterceptor auditableEntitySaveChangesInterceptor)
                : base(options)
        {
            _mediator = mediator;
            _auditableEntitySaveChangesInterceptor = auditableEntitySaveChangesInterceptor;
        }

        public DbSet<DataHistorical> DataHistoricals => Set<DataHistorical>();
        public DbSet<DataIndicator> DataIndicators => Set<DataIndicator>();


        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
 optionsBuilder.UseInMemoryDatabase("SampleDb");
            optionsBuilder.AddInterceptors(_auditableEntitySaveChangesInterceptor);
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }

        public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            await _mediator.DispatchDomainEvents(this);

            return await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
        }

    }
```

Can you please let me know where I went wrong?

Comment: In-memory provider do not support migrations.